# get the last modified dat of css or js on jsp

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, java-io, last-modified

I was wondering how we can find the last modified date of css and js on jsp, the way I know through is using the lastModified(). Now what I was looking for is that I am including around 5-6 js and 2,3 css and at include time how to find out last modified time for each file so that I can force browser not to cache the old one and take new css or js

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-filter-files-based-on-their-last-modified-dates.html

Comment: thanx @chridam but I was looking for a more clean way since I am including 7-8 file . Is there any way I can perform this check on include time ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to this exact problem. I think this is what you're looking for:

https://gist.github.com/varunachar/5335579 - Cache Buster

It uses a JSP taglib to create append the Last Modified date to the javascript file.

(All credit goes to varunachar. I did not write this code)